# Getting the names and sizes of all the files in a folder

Tags: c++, file, directory

So I need to find the names and sizes of all the files in a certain folder (finding out the number of files in the folder is not necessary).

How would this be done and would I need to put the program in the same folder as the files I'm trying to find the name and size of?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Comment: See also [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) on Linux, in particular if you want to recurse in the file tree